# get aws_secret_access_key to store in ~/.boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Im trying to store in `~/.boto` file the user `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` keys.

I'm already storing `aws_access_key_id` correctly, but now, I don't know how can I get `aws_secret_access_key` so I can store it in `~/.boto` file.

Do you know how can I get `aws_secret_access_key`?

```
import  os
import boto.iam.connection

username = "user"

conection = boto.iam.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
conection.create_access_key(username)
conection.create_access_key(username)

k = conection.get_all_access_keys(username)
ackey =  k['list_access_keys_response']['list_access_keys_result']['access_key_metadata'][0]['access_key_id']
# and how to return the aws_secret_access_key??

with open(os.path.expanduser("~/.boto"),"w") as f:
    f.write("[Credentials]")
    f.write("/n")
    f.write("aws_access_key_id" + ackey)
    f.write("/n")
    f.write("aws_secret_access_key" + ??)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `secret_access_key` associated with AWS API credentials is returned via the API when the access key is created.  You must store the key at that point because it is never returned by the IAM service again.  If you change your code to be something like this, you can capture the secret key at key creation time.

```
conection = boto.iam.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
response = connection.create_access_key(username)
secret_access_key = response['create_access_key_response']['create_access_key_result']['access_key']['secret_access_key']
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But with your solution Im getting an error:  secret_access_key = response['create_access_key_response']['create_access_key_result']['access_key']['secret_access_key']
KeyError: 'create_access_key_response

Comment: I have verified that the above is correct.  Try printing out the value of ``response`` and see what it contains.

Comment: Dont contains [create_acess_key_response]. It only contains {u'create_user_response': {u'create_user_result': {u'user': {u'path': u'/', u'create_date': u'', u'user_id': u'', u'arn': u'', u'user_name': u''}}, u'response_metadata': {u'request_id': u''}}}

Comment: I think that's because you are calling ``create_user()`` and not ``create_access_key()``.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue!